# Validate texbox inside a Repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, repeater, asprepeater

I have requirement something like this
[image: Repeter]

I have a repeater,it contains **set of 12 Textboxes(To & From)**,

now i want to validate each set,i.e in a set either  both textboxes are fill or no one is fill.
if **From** is fill then there must be a **To** for it and vice-versa.

and also in the repeater,at least one **[from-To]** set must be fill.

How can I do?

Comment: Are you matching sets with anything? Like any id or tag? I mean how do we progratically understand a box is pair of another?

Comment: no,i just am taking the name="txtFrom" for From-textbox and name= "txtTo" for To-Textbox

Comment: At least share your mark-up code. Its impossible to answer without that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASP.NET custom validator control in the detail template of your repeater. Hook it up to an event handler and validate the row according to your rules on the server side.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.140%29.aspx